# When i am searching in magento it shows duplicate result

Tags: magento-1.7

[image]

category is showing duplicate, means one with corresponding category,another with /, i don't want to display '/' one

Comment: What have you tried so far to try and fix this? it seems it shows a number of products named "Barilla" and the number of products in a category named "barilla/". Are you using a 3rd party extension for your search?

Comment: i have checked url rewrite and re index all url but didn't work,barilla is only a category , i am using normal magento search i think

Answer (score 1):

The suggestions show what other people searched in your website.
Maybe someone searched for the category name, and other people searched for the category name with a slash.
This is the default behavior. If you have an extension installed for search you should contact the developer.